# Ruby - Error: "unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end"

Tags: ruby, twitter, raspberry-pi

First off, I'm new to ruby so I apologize if I did something that's not conventional. I am just trying to run a simple script that interacts with twitter. It works perfectly fine on my macbook but when I try to run it on my raspberry pi I get this error: "unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end." I found posts involving this error, but I didn't feel like the answers helped me.

It's mainly just throwing me off because it's not happening on my mac.

This is the script (or at least a portion of it) I'm having problems with:

```
#encoding: UTF-8

require 'tweetstream'
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'

puts TweetStream::VERSION

c_key           = 'xxxx'
c_secret        = 'xxxx'
oa_token        = 'xxxx'
oa_token_secret = 'xxxx'

TweetStream.configure do |config|
        config.consumer_key       = c_key
        config.consumer_secret    = c_secret
        config.oauth_token        = oa_token
        config.oauth_token_secret = oa_token_secret
        config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new( c_key, c_secret)
access_token = OAuth::Token.new( oa_token, oa_token_secret)

client = TweetStream::Client.new

keywords = ['word','word']

client.userstream do |status|
        if keywords.any? {|str| status.text.downcase.include? str} && status.user.id.to_s != '11111111111'

                unless status.text[0,4].include? 'RT @'

                        puts "#{status.id}: #{status.text}\n"

                end
        end
end
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

---

Okay so I just copied over my code from my other computer again and it's working fine. I have no clue what happened because I never really fiddled with it when I brought it over the first time. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: can you give full error stack? I don't see any error in this part..

Comment: Just the location, which after some changed suggested below is the last 'end,' then "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input."

Comment: Give the full error stack, copy from your editor and paste it here..

Answer (score 0):

## How to find elusive syntax errors in Ruby

I'm not going to tell you where your syntax error is, but I'll tell you how to find out.

Start commenting out code.  This is easiest done with an editor that allows you to highlight a block of code and comment it out with one command (for example, in Emacs, c-C c-C toggles whether or not the highlighted block is commented-out).  Start with the part of your code where you most recently made a modification (if you're not sure, check your version control system to see what you've changed).  Pick some part of it--perhaps half, to comment out.  Be sure that you're commenting out belongs together--for example, don't comment out half of a while loop--comment out the whole thing.

Now load your program.  Do you still get the syntax error?  If not, you've just identified where it must be.  Take some of the code you commented out, and un-comment it out.  If so, find another block of code and comment it out.

Lather, rinse repeat.

You don't have to worry about whether your program *runs* -- if it loads without a syntax error, it will no doubt fail because of all the commented out code.  All you're doing is finding out where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 0):

Funny story....I had the same error before and it was driving me NUTS for like an hour. No kidding. I refused to give up. I just could not figure it out! Why the error? My code was on-point.

And then....I happen to hit the scroll-down bar only to see that there was already an "end" inserted below like 2 lines down!! I couldn't see it on the screen. There was an extra!!! Smh...

Once I took it out...my "bundle exec rake test" passed. Sometimes it's the little things :)

Answer (score -1):

change

```
unless status.text[0,4].include? 'RT @'
  puts "#{status.id}: #{status.text}\n"
end
```

to:

```
if !status.text[0,4].include? 'RT @'
  puts "#{status.id}: #{status.text}\n"
end
```

or:

```
puts "#{status.id}: #{status.text}\n" unless status.text[0,4].include? 'RT @'
```

unless something is equivalent to if !something

unless does not need an `end` for it.

Comment: Sorry never used Unless that way before.

Comment: even so if you put `puts "#{status.id}: #{status.text}\n" unless status.text[0,4].include? 'RT @'` it would eliminate one `end` tag and closer to finding out the problem.

Comment: So I made that change and the error location moved from the line with then 'end' for the 'if' statement to the line with the 'end' for the 'do.' It also changed the error to "unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input.